# Fast Ethernet module for Cisco 2620

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco 2620 Router.

It comes with one fast ethernet port built in (circled in red), and one old AUI ethernet module is installed (circled in blue).

[image: back of router]

I figure I can put a transceiver on the AUI interface to get a second RJ45 connector. What I'd really like to have is a second fast ethernet connector.

The ideal candidate to achieve this would be the NM-1FE-TX module.

[image: nm-1fe-tx module]

Cisco claims [on their website](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps274/products_data_sheet09186a0080091b89.html) that this module is not suitable for the Cisco 2620 and Cisco 2620XM. It says so in "Table 2   Physical Limitation of Serial Modules per Chassis".

Indeed, this module was designed for the 3600 series of routers. I've seen claims on the internet, however, of people having this module on a 2620XM, and it being fully functional.

This claim gains some credibility because of the fact that in Cisco's own Packet Tracer software, you can install this module on the 2620XM router.

[image: packet tracer screenshot]

I'm looking for a definitive answer.

Will this module work on a Cisco 2620? Is there perhaps another way to get a second fast ethernet port on this device?

Comment: I think that's a HSSI (High speed serial interface) port not AUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the NM-xFE2W won't work in a non-xm router. However you could try a 16 ports NM:

[image]

It's a [cisco NM-16ESW](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2t/12_2t8/feature/guide/ft1636nm.html), and it [should work fine](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/12_2x/12_2xt/release/notes/rn2600xt.html#wp66775).

Answer (score 2):

```
NM-1FE2W and NM-1FE2W-V2: 1-port 10/100 Ethernet 2 WAN Card Slot Network Module
NM-2FE2W and NM-2FE2W-V2: 2-port 10/100 Ethernet 2 WAN Card Slot Network Module
NM-1FE1R2W: 1-port 10/100 Ethernet 1 4/16 Token Ring 2 WAN Card Slot NM
NM-1FE-FX-V2: 1-Port Fast Ethernet Network Module, FX Only
NM-2W:  2 WAN Card Slot Network Module (No LAN Interface)
```

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps259/product_data_sheet09186a00801aa71c.html

Comment: I don't see any mention of the 2620 on that page.

Comment: The 2620 is covered under the "2600 series" umbrella. According to that page the NM-2W is the only supported module on the 2600 series but according to [this page](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/net_mgmt/ciscoworks_ciscoview/device_support/table/cvsdt.html#rtr2600) there are plenty of FE modules that work. There are a lot of conflicting reports around the net about whether these work in 2620 routers. My guess is that **genuine** cisco modules will work but there are a lot of fakes out there.